# ansible uri replace + sign with space in body or jenkins api replace it, who has issue?

Tags: python, ansible, jenkins, uri

I am using jenkins api to create credential by ansible.

```
- name: Add credential to add node
  uri:
      body: |
          json={
              "": "0",
              "credentials": {
                "scope": "GLOBAL",
                "id": "jenkins_linux_slave1_auth",
                "username": "jenkins",
                "password": "123456",
                "privateKeySource": {
                  "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
                  "privateKey": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nProc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\nPRIVATE+KEY+WITH+PLUS+SIGN\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
                },
                "description": "Jenkins Linux Slave1 Authentication",
                "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
              }
            }
      force_basic_auth: yes
      method: POST
      password: "{{ jenkins_user_token }}"
      status_code: 302
      url: "{{ jenkins_url }}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials"
      user: "{{ jenkins_user }}"
      validate_certs: no
  tags:
      - credential
```

This create credential in jenkins, but when I check the private key in jenkins, it replace `+` with **(space)**

[image: Replace + with Space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jenkins API accepts normal URL encoded form data, but usually with only one field, named `json`.

The Ansible uri module *does not* URL encode the `body` when sending normal URL encoded form data. You need to do this yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in ansible? I tried to find `urlencode` filter, but seems its not working.

Comment: Michael, is there any way to pass `urlencoded` value in payload ?